# Wifi Automation or Share - Can I use my home WiFi anywhere in my Mobile

Tags: automation, wifi

Is it possible that I use my home Wifi at anywhere in my Mobile. Like home automation features.

I just want to use Internet in my mobile from my Home WiFi.

Comment: If your home network has a working internet connection obviously you can use internet in your mobile by connecting to your home wifi. Can you please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you take a portable hotspot with you, but you need to be connected to your internet.

If your talking about somewhere outside your Home WiFi, then you need to get 4G.

Comment: I unable to understand your answer. Kindly explain.

Comment: if your trying to get internet on ur phone anywhere outside, then you're better off buying 4G, which is a subscription from a provider.

Comment: if you are talking about just having internet on your phone in your house, maybe try to turn on your WiFi and connect to it?